# formating a phone number in the postresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can you format a phone number in an postgreSQL query?  I have a phone number column.  The phone numbers are held as such:  1234567890.  I am wondering if postgres will format to (123) 456-7890.  I can do this outside the query, I am using php, but it would be nice if I was able to have the output of the query like (123) 456-7890

Comment: So, it is stored as a number, not as a String, correct?

Comment: Um, phone numbers are not actually numbers, they're really strings that just happen to consist of digit characters. Fix your schema first. Do you have to deal with international numbers or just North American ones? What about extensions?

Comment: Just a quick comment in that I recommend you enforce the right format through the web-interface with let say JQuery or Javascrip--then store that string directly into the DB. I know this doesn't answer your question, but it's definitely better design, I would say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function

something like:

```
  SELECT 
 '(' || SUBSTRING((PhoneNumber, 1, 3) + ') ' || SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 4,3) || '-' || SUBSTRING((PhoneNumber,7,4)
```

Comment: I don't think you can append strings in postgres by using `+`

Comment: sorry, I have fixed || instead of +

Comment: This is still incorrect! I went ahead and fixed it for my query:
```'
(' || SUBSTRING(callers.phone_number::text, 1, 3) || ') ' || SUBSTRING(callers.phone_number::text, 4,3) || '-' || SUBSTRING(callers.phone_number::text,7,4)
```

Answer (score 5):

This will work for you:

```
SELECT
  '( ' || SUBSTRING(CAST(NUMBER AS VARCHAR) FROM 1 FOR 3) || ' ) ' 
 || SUBSTRING(CAST(NUMBER AS VARCHAR) FROM 4 FOR 3) || '-' 
 || SUBSTRING(CAST(NUMBER AS VARCHAR) FROM 7 FOR LENGTH(CAST(NUMBER AS VARCHAR)))
FROM
  YOURTABLE
```

Also, here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/99462/20).

Comment: @Kyzer If you have found an answer, never forget to upvote/mark it as the correct answer, so others can find it easily.

Answer (score 5):

Use a regex, it is more flexible and easy to read. Assuming the numbers are in field "phone":

```
SELECT regexp_replace(phone, '(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})', '(\1) \2-\3') phone FROM table;
```

You could also spruce it up in various ways: by adding optional digits for country codes, by allowing for multiple numbers, or more.

For example, to first strip non-digits and fixed half-formatted values like (123) 4567890:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(regexp_replace(phone, '\D', '', 'g'), '(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})', '(\1) \2-\3') phone FROM table;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '(' || SUBSTRING(phone FROM 1 FOR 3) || ') ' || 
              SUBSTRING(phone FROM 4 FOR 3) || '-' || 
              SUBSTRING(phone FROM 7 FOR 4) 
FROM table;
```

This will return all phone numbers with the format (123) 456-7890, however there will be no column header. To remedy this, use the following SELECT statement:

SELECT '(' || SUBSTRING(phone FROM 1 FOR 3) || ') ' || SUBSTRING(phone FROM 4 FOR 3) || '-' || SUBSTRING(phone FROM 7 FOR 4) AS Phone FROM chapters;

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please format code as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, it makes it easier to read for everyone

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using the `FORMAT` function. See [Postgresql string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-string.html) for details.

Your example would look like

```
SELECT FORMAT('(%s)%s-%s', SUBSTR(phone, 1, 3), SUBSTR(phone, 4, 3), SUBSTR(phone, 7, 4))
FROM table;
```